# consulta SQL para mostrar cliente y total de productos y costos

Tags: sql

Indique consulta Sql en donde obtenga las siguientes columnas compras totales, agrupadas por cliente y totalizadas para las siguientes Tablas:
Datos:

```
Tabla CLIENTE                   
CAMPO        TIPO
---------------------------
DNI          Char(10)
Nombre       Varchar(30)
Apellido     Varchar(30)


Tabla  Pedidos
CAMPO        TIPO
---------------------------    
npedido      Numérico(4)
fecha        Datetime
cantidad     Numeric(8)
monto        Money
Cliente_dni  Char(10)
```

> Indicaciones: Usar los comandos sum, count, group by, order by,
>   compute, join

Estoy usando lo siguiente:

```
select nombre, sum(cantidad), sum(monto)
from cliente, pedidos
group by nombre
```

El resultado esperado seria si pedro jimenes compra 10 articulos de costo 10 c/u:

Nombrecliente - cantidad - monto

pedro jimenes   10         100

El resultado en la columna cantidad y monto es el mismo para todos los clientes.

Como separo los productos por cliente?

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos usas? ¿Qué quieres decir exactamente *compras totales, agrupadas por cliente y totalizadas*? Es  una expresión algo confusa, parece querer decir compras totales, pero lo de *totalizadas* a qué se refiere? Convendría que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/174073/edit) poniendo un ejemplo sencillo de los datos y del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clausula join para relacionar los registro de ambas tablas por medio del campo dni en la tabla cliente y el campo Cliente_dni en la tabla Pedidos. La clausula Group by se utiliza para agrupar datos, en este caso se agrupa por medio de la columna DNI y así la consulta retorna de forma agrupada y totalizada los registros de los clientes.

Ejemplo:

```
Select 
  CONCAT(c.Nombre, " ", c.Apellido) as cliente, 
  COUNT(p.npedido) as NumeroPedidos,
  SUM(p.cantidad) as Cantidad,
  SUM(p.monto) as MontoTotal
FROM CLIENTE c
 INNER JOIN Pedidos p 
 ON (c.DNI = p.Cliente_dni)
GROUP BY c.DNI
ORDER BY c.Nombre;
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solucion de la siguiente manera:

```
select
  cliente.dni, cliente.nombre, cliente.apellido,
  SUM(pedidos2.cantidad),
  SUM(pedidos2.monto)
from cliente
  inner join pedidos2
  on cliente.dni = pedidos2.cliente_dni
group by cliente.dni, cliente.nombre, cliente.apellido
order by dni
```

Gracias.